# Netsuite Vendor Merging Error: You have modified the originating subrecord, and the clone can no longer be merged

Tags: netsuite

When I attempted to merge two vendors, I was introduced this error below:

"The merge of the entity 'Vendor Name' was blocked for the following reasons: The entities cannot be merged. Creation of the merged entity leads to following errors: You have modified the originating subrecord, and the clone can no longer be merged. To perform a merge, the clone's originating subrecord must not change before the merge. You must create a new clone. "

I suspect this is caused by the distribution template app our company recently installed. Has anyone have experience with this error?